# Prove that a function is differentiable at $0$ when $h(x)=x^2f(x)$.

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f : (−1, 1) \to\mathbb R$ be a bounded function. Let $g : (−1, 1) \to\mathbb R$ defined by $g(x) = xf(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Use this result to prove that the function $h : (−1, 1) \to\mathbb R$ defined by $h(x) = x^2f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, and find $h'(0)$. Note: The product rule for derivatives cannot be applied here.

Do I just do it where $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}$ by definition of differentiable, thus $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2
f(x)-(0)^2f(0)}{x-0}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2f(x)}{x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x)\\&=0f'(0)\\&=0?\end{align}$$

Comment: The only wrong part is using $f’(0).$ Nothing says that $f$ is even continuous at zero. Instead, you need that $f$ is bounded to get $xf(x)\to 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Apart from the mistake of writing $f'(0)$ instead of $f(0)$, there's nothing wrong with this argument; even though it's unknown if $f$ is continuous at $0$, it was assumed that $g(x)=xf(x)$ is, and that's the expression whose limit is being taken.

Answer (score 2):

The last step does not work like that.

Rather, you need to let $M>0$ be such that $|f(x)|\leq M$, as $f$ is a bounded function.

Then $|xf(x)|\leq M|x|$ and we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}M|x|=0$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}xf(x)=0$ by Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: You don't need to use the Squeeze Theorem to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x)=0$. It was assumed that $g(x)=xf(x)$ is continuous at $0$, so $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=g(0)$, that is $\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x)=0\cdot f(0)=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, OP wrote $0\cdot f'(0)$, I wonder if he made the typo or used the continuity of $g$.

Comment: it's most likely a typo.